# Cannot cast from DialogFragment to View - any workarounds?

Tags: android, date, casting, dialog, fragment

I in these lines of code eclipse gives me an error on the third like that states:"Cannot cast DialogFragment to View", is there any workaround this? Or other option/options?

```
DialogFragment dateClock = new DatePickerFrag();
View homeSection = findViewById(R.layout.introducere_date);
((LinearLayout) homeSection).addView(((View) dateClock));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be one approach to show TimePickerDialog -

```
public static class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
                        implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

  @Override
  public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
    return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
            DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
  }

  public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    // Do something with the time chosen by the user
  }
}
```

and then

```
public void showTimePickerDialog() {
  DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
  newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
}
```